# How to pivot all columns in Tableau

Tags: python, pivot-table, tableau-api, data-analysis

[image]

I have this data set in Tableau and I want to pivot all the columns. The only option I have is to select one by one is there any option?
This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: perhaps this can help: https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2018/06/pivoting.html

Comment: It says to do on tableau prep. Not possible on tableau itself.

Comment: Like most tools, you can use shift-click to extend a contiguous selection, or control-click to add/remove individual items to a selection. So you can quickly select a large number of columns whether using the grid view or list view on the data source page. You don't have to select columns one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like the GIF below.  Actually you can use <kbd>shift</kbd>+ click to select all column at once.  And yes, it can be done in tableau desktop.  Note you cannot unpivot (pivot_wider) in Tableau desktop though, for which you have to use Prep.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks that’s really helpful. But the things is that this data set has columns 1800 to 2021. And it isn’t happening with shift + click. I tried scrolling through it.. but the issue persists

Comment: So what Kirti?  Just select `1800` hold `shift` and drag upto last column with mouse and click on last column.  All columns will be selected!

Comment: See new Gif added

Comment: I obviously tried that.! but wasn’t happening so Let me try that again. And thank you so much for your time .!